# angular2-highcharts throwing exceptions when we port a Graph

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

Angular2-highcharts is throwing a wierd exception when I am trying to port my existing graph. The code for my graph is as shown below:-

http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/dx2vj8k1/

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    marginLeft: 10
  },

  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
        dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },

  xAxis: {
    left: '50%',
    categories: ['15-19', '20-21'],
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickWidth: 0,
    labels: {
      align: 'left',
      x: -18
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Age Group',
      align: 'high',
      rotation: 0,
      x: 40
    }
  },

  yAxis: [{
    left: '55%',
    width: '45%',
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      x: -160,
      text: 'Female'
    },
    gridLineWidth: 0
  }, {
    reversed: true,
    width: '45%',
    offset: 0,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      x: 170,
      text: 'Male'
    },
    gridLineWidth: 0
  }],

  series: [{
    data: [1, 3]
  }, {
    data: [2, 5],
    yAxis: 1
  }]
});
```

When I try to port this to angular2-highcharts, I get a pretty bizarre error as shown below. What am I doing Wrong?

The plnkr is here http://plnkr.co/edit/UvOmYi?p=preview

The error which I see is below:-

[image]

The output of the above Plnkr is here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error is because of percentage issue while defining width,left,right.
angular2-highcharts is highcharts plugin for Angular is based on Typescript.

So you cannot use `width: '45%',` directly because it is string instead use `width:window.innerWidth * .45`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Bp3O8SwWjwkLFCRkrQPa?p=preview

```
chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    marginLeft: 10
  },

  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    left: window.innerWidth * .52,
    categories: ['15-19', '20-21'],
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickWidth: 0,
    labels: {
      align: 'left',
      x: -18
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Age Group',
      align: 'high',
      x: 10
    }
  },

  yAxis: [{
    left: window.innerWidth * .55,
    width:window.innerWidth * .45,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      x: -160,
      text: 'Female'
    },
    gridLineWidth: 0
  }, {
    reversed: true,
    width: window.innerWidth * .45,
    offset: 0,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      x: 170,
      text: 'Male'
    },
    gridLineWidth: 0
  }],

  series: [{
    data: [1, 3]
  }, {
    data: [2, 5],
    yAxis: 1
  }]
 };
```

[image]